# Autoit script to automate the audacity track down menu with dynamic mouseclick

Tags: scripting, autoit, audacity

I am trying to automate some 600 mp3 files for church to combine instrument and voice into one track so I can use the mixer to do left or right channel. when I combined two sounds file, I need to select left channel for first track and right channel for second track.

the problem is that if audacity is fixed screen/location, the mouseclick is working fine. But I moved the script to laptop/Desktop, it won't work since mouse coordinates are not same.

Is there a way to select down track menu from audacity to select left or right channel? There are no shortcuts at current version.  If someone can help, I appreciate for you opinion and times.

Br, Adnrew

**This codes worked great for me. Thanks, guys.**

```
 Opt("MouseCoordMode", 0) ;1=absolute, 0=relative, 2=client

 ;set left channel
 ControlClick($FileNameL, "","","Left",1,90,13)
 Send("{SHIFTDOWN}l{SHIFTUP}")
 Sleep(1000)

 ;set right channel
 ControlClick($FileNameL, "","","Left",1,60,162)
 Send("{SHIFTDOWN}r{SHIFTUP}")
 Sleep(1000)
 Send("{CTRLDOWN}a{CTRLUP}")
 ;MsgBox(0,"File Size","waiting")
 Send("{ALTDOWN}tx{ALTUP}")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need

```
Opt("MouseCoordMode", 0) ;1=absolute, 0=relative, 2=client
```

This will make your clicks relative to the window you are  working with.

Use window info Tool to find those coordinates.
Go to options and set Coord mode to Window.

You can also use

```
ControlClick ( "title", "text", controlID [, button [, clicks [, x [, y]]]] )
```

Any of these two methods are not dependant on your screen resolution.